# How generate ID uniquely in two featureStores with GeoTools?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geotools

I have a PostGIS datastore in GeoTools as follow:

```
JDBCDataStore dataStore = ...
```

and I have 2 tables(or FeatureStore in GeoTools) as follow:

```
SimpleFeatureStore table1Store = (SimpleFeatureStore) dataStore.getFeatureSource("table1")
SimpleFeatureStore table2Store = (SimpleFeatureStore) dataStore.getFeatureSource("table2")
```

I can insert data in two tables. Inserted record ID generated automatically. I want generated ID in two tables be unique. For example if a record insert to `table1` and id `22` generated, next insert to `table2` generate ID `23`.

My resolve is change default value of column `id` in `table2` to `nextval('table1_id_seq')`, but when I want to insert in `table2` occurs an error as follows:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: currval of sequence "table1_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session.
```

What can I do to achieve this goal?

Comment: have you added a row to table 1 before you try to add a row to table 2?

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue is a PostGIS/PostgreSQL one rather than GeoTools. I also suspect that whatever you are trying to achieve has a better solution than messing with FIDs.

But that said something like this might work (but I haven't tested it):

```
    FeatureWriter<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> writer1 = ds.getFeatureWriter("table1", Transaction.AUTO_COMMIT);
    FeatureWriter<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> writer2 = ds.getFeatureWriter("table2", Transaction.AUTO_COMMIT);
    SimpleFeature f = writer1.next();
    int counter = 0;
    sfb.set("name", "test1");
    f = sfb.buildFeature("MyID." + counter);
    counter++;
    writer1.write();
    SimpleFeature f2 = writer2.next();
    sfb.set("name", "test2");
    f2 = sfb.buildFeature("MyID." + counter);
    writer2.write();
```

Comment: No result - org.geotools.jdbc: Update called with no attributes, doing nothing